# Expectated value

Tags: probability, expectation

Four letters are typed at random so that each of the $26$ latin alphabet letters is equally likely and the letters are typed independently of one another. What is the expected number of times the word OF appears in this four letters long random text?

My attempt is

Let

$X$: random variable where O appears

$Y$: random variable where F appears

$$E(X) = 0 + P(X=1)x_1 = 1/26$$

$$E(Y) = 0 + P(X=1)x_1 = 1/26$$

$$\Rightarrow E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y) = 2/26 $$
(because i think $X$ and $Y$ are joint rather than independent since it should happen at the same time but i am very uncertain)

Thank you very much

Comment: I am not so sure why my post is voted down :( Is there something wrong with this question. Please tell me:(

Comment: Don't take the down vote personally.  They are meant for quality control.  I see nothing wrong with your post, however.    You didn't solve the problem correctly, but you made an honest attempt.  You stated your question clearly.  Perhaps it's because you didn't use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  to format your question.  You ought to do that in the future.

Comment: thank you!!  i get it :):)

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways "OF" can appear in the string: at the beginning, in the middle, or at the end. Each one happens with probability $\frac1{26^2}$.

These events are related in varying ways; the event that "OF" appears in the beginning is disjoint from "OF" appearing in the middle (they can't happen at the same time) and independent from "OF" appearing at the end. But that's irrelevant.

If we define

- $X_1 = 1$ if the first two letters are "OF" and $0$ otherwise,
- $X_2 = 1$ if the middle two letters are "OF" and $0$ otherwise, and
- $X_3 = 1$ if the last two letters are "OF" and $0$ otherwise,

then $X_1 + X_2 + X_3$ is the total number of occurrences of "OF". By linearity of expectation (which always applies, whether or not the random variables are independent), 
$$
   \mathbb E[X_1 + X_2 + X_3] = \mathbb E[X_1] + \mathbb E[X_2] + \mathbb E[X_3] = \frac1{26^2} + \frac1{26^2} + \frac1{26^2} = \frac3{26^2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. Linearity of expextation always applies no matter RVs are independent or not,  and you also have said that it is not relevant to take into account that they are independent or disjoint or joint in this question. Is it what you mean? I first thought that the event of “O” appears and “F” appears are joint since they must appear together. Could you clarify that what is wrong with my thinking?

Comment: To answer the first part of your comment; yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: For the second part of your comment: you can consider the events "First letter is O" and "Second letter is F" on your way to figuring out the probability of "First two letters are OF", and in that case they're independent because they involve different letters, but you want to move away from them in the end because you're not interested in counting O's or F's by themselves, only when they appear together.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realized that this approach is good if the questions give me long length of letters. I have then encountered a question where i have to find expected value of letter APPLE on the sequence of letters with length 1000. And i did exactly the same the way you have showed me and it perfectly worked. Once again, thank you :):)

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the random variable $X$= number of times the sequence 'OF' appears.

Notice that $X$ can take on the values: $0,1$ or $2$. So, in this case, $$E[X] = 0 \cdot P(X=0)+1\cdot P(X=1)+2 \cdot P(X=2)$$

Now these are all the possibilities where the sequence 'OF' appears:

- $OFxx: 26 \cdot26-1=675$ is the number of ways you can obtain this (because each $x$ can take on $26$ values, except the case when they are 'OF' once again)
- $xOFx: 26 \cdot26 =676$ number of ways to obtain this.
- $xxOF : 26 \cdot26-1= 675 $ number of ways, following the first reasoning.
- $OFOF$: $1$ way to obtain this.

So then

$P(X=0)= \frac{26^4-2(675)-676-1}{26^4}= \frac{454949}{26^4}$

$P(X=1)= \frac{2(675)+676}{26^4}=\frac{2026}{26^4}$

$P(X=2)= \frac{1}{26^4}$

So finally:

$$E[X]=0\cdot\frac{454949}{26^4}+1\cdot \frac{2026}{26^4} + 2 \cdot\frac{1}{26^4} = \frac{1013}{228488}+\frac{1}{228488}= \frac{3}{676} = \frac{3}{26^2}.$$

Comment: This approach is also clear and helpful with enough details and explanation. Thanks so much. I really get this!

Comment: @tabitha96 If Thomas's answer helped you, I urge you to accept it. (Among other things, it will put this answer above the incorrect answer, helping other people that want to understand expected value.)

Answer (score 0):

You need $O$ to appear in one of the first three places, with probability $\frac 3{26}$ then $F$ to appear next with probability $\frac 1{26}$ so it would appear it is $\frac 3{26^2}$ but you have counted $OFOF$ twice so it is $\frac 3{26^2}-\frac 1{26^4}$

Comment: Why would we have to have O to appear in first three places but only one place for F ? Why it is not like O to appear in 2 places and F in the other two places ( for instance)? Thank you :):)

Comment: @tabitha96 $OF$ can be 'slotted' in the first and second, second and third, or third and fourth slot. In each of those configurations, $O$ has to come first, hence being in the first, second, or third slot.

Comment: For a given place of $O$ there is only one place for $F$.  You have $OFxx, xOFx, xxOF$ for three places for the $O$, not two.

Comment: You're computing the probability, not the expectation.

Comment: thank u. i get it to the part how they should appear but what you mean by counting OFOF twice? i am not really aware of that !

Comment: You count it once as $OFxx$ and once as $xxOF$.  The $\frac 3{26^2}$ counts each of these.